# iTextSharp: How to add page number to multiple pdf file after merged them together

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp, version 5.5.8.0 in a Windows Form application. Here is the code I used to merge two pdf files. My task is to add page number in merged file.

```
private void MergePDFFiles()
{
    string fileSuffix = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".pdf";

    string[] lstFiles = new string[2];
    lstFiles[0] = @"/File_1.pdf";
    lstFiles[1] = @"/File_2.pdf";

    PdfReader reader = null;
    Document sourceDocument = null;
    PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = null;
    PdfImportedPage importedPage;
    string outputPdfPath = @"/MergedPageNo_" + fileSuffix;

    sourceDocument = new Document();
    pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(sourceDocument, new System.IO.FileStream(outputPdfPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create));

    sourceDocument.Open();

    try
    {
        for (int f = 0; f < lstFiles.Length - 0; f++)
        {
            int pages = get_pageCount(lstFiles[f]);

            reader = new PdfReader(lstFiles[f]);
            for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
            {                      
                importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        sourceDocument.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}`
```

Comment: What problems do you face with achieving what you want?

Comment: You might want to look at `PageStamp` examples.

Comment: @Wai Ha Lee: I'd like to add page number to merged file. If File_1.pdf has 3 pages, then, when the first page in File_2.pdf was added, the page number would be 4. I couldn't find a right place or method to achieve it. Please advise.

Comment: See @mkl's [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35597296/231316)

Comment: mkl's code works. thanks mkl and @Chris.